# How can I implement vanity URL's in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, url-routing

I want users to able to have a profile page at site.com/myNameHere.  Rails looks for a controller named "myNameHere." Is it possible to setup routes.rb so that if the controller is not found, "myNameHere" gets sent as a parameter to another controller?

Comment: Just make sure that if you choose to use the vanity gem you know that there is a vulrenability in the vanities_controller.rb in the redirect_to just add :only_path => true and you should be good

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a route like this:

```
map.profile_link '/:username', :controller => 'profiles', :action => 'show'
```

Be sure to add it low enough in the file, below your resources, that it doesn't interfere with other routes.  It should be lowest priority.  Next, you need to change your show action to use a username instead of id:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

That's all there is to it.  Happy coding!

**UPDATE:**

I've expanded this answer into a full blog post, [Vanity URLs in Ruby on Rails Routes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150514194739/http://kconrails.com/2010/01/25/vanity-urls-for-ruby-on-rails-routes/).  I have additional code samples and a more thorough explanation.

Comment: You'll want to keep in mind that a wildcard route at the root level will trap what should be top level 404 errors. I.e. http://domain.com/askdjasd . So you probably want to add some exception handling (not found) in your show action and render your 404 instead of a 500 error.

Comment: Building on what Dave Rapin said, you can use `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :your_404_method` in your controller to show 404 errors automatically when no user is found. You will have to raise that error manually if you're using a `find_by_attribute` method because they don't automatically raise them. So use `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])` and the associated rescue and you're golden.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for is that you don't want your users to give themselves a name that coincides with your controller name. You'll need some sort of exclusion list.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would update this for Rails 3. I have a field 'website' in my user model that is going to act as the vanity route, and I am going to route to a static page for each vanity route. I want to display all of a users 'events' if the vanity route is called.

```
#config/routes.rb
  get '/:website', :controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'vanity'

#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
  def vanity
      @user = User.find_by_website(params[:website])
    if @user != nil #in case someone puts in a bogus url I redirect to root
      @events = @user.events
    else
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

#app/views/static_pages/vanity.html.erb
<h1><%= @user.website  %> events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Starts at</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.title %></td>
    <td><%= event.starts_at %></td>
    <td><%= event.description %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I think this is a good alternative if you don't want to use a gem.