# How to map users in root URL in Rails 2.x routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, accessibility, url-routing

My routes.rb look like this:

```
#...
map.resources :users
map.root :controller => "main"
#...
```

My app user's profiles are something like:

> http://www.railsapp.com/**users/3**

I would like to change it to:

> http://www.railsapp.com/**3**

Or even:

> http://www.railsapp.com/**username**

How Rails 2.x router handles this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout some previous answers for 'vanity' urls:

[How can I implement vanity URL's in a Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137392/how-can-i-implement-vanity-urls-in-a-rails-application)

[How to implement "short" nested vanity urls in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575475/how-to-implement-short-nested-vanity-urls-in-rails)