# Create a new URL path for each user in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I create in real-time a new URL path in Ruby on Rails?

For example: I want my users to have name.XXX.com or XXX.com/name.

FYi I'm hosting the code on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at subdomain-fu plugin.

https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout some previous answers for 'vanity' urls in the case for example.com/username:

[How can I implement vanity URL's in a Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137392/how-can-i-implement-vanity-urls-in-a-rails-application)

[How to implement "short" nested vanity urls in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575475/how-to-implement-short-nested-vanity-urls-in-rails)

As for subdomains, other suggestions by @Arkan, @Anton, @tadman are a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a wildcard CNAME or A record to point your names over in the first place, which in this case would be `*.XXX.com`, to handle this on a DNS level. The second part is in examining your `request.host` header which will be `name.XXX.com` or whatever is used. You can use this to set variables in a `before_filter` block.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is like tadman described: set up a DNS record and write a rewrite rule for Apache/nginx/whatever which will eat subdomain and add it to params.

As an option, set up a middleware (more about it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html), where you can rewrite/route the requests before the get processed by Rails routing. Being prepared carefully, this can help implementing very sophisticated things :)