# Removing resource name from rails urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that I want to have reflect a similar url style to that of github:

/:user/:project

I can do this directly through match but this pretty much undoes the usefulness of resources routing. Does anyone know of a good way to get rails to use the above style of url for certain resources without having to hack up every path?

I've looked at some of the slug stuff but this seems to leave the '/users/' part of the path in which is what I want to remove.

Thanks

Comment: This has been discussed before — e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137392/how-can-i-implement-vanity-urls-in-a-rails-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195518/create-a-new-url-path-for-each-user-in-ror. For more info and help check http://kconrails.com/2010/01/25/vanity-urls-for-ruby-on-rails-routes/ and https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu

Comment: Thanks. I was already aware of all these. It's not what I'm trying to ask. In effect I'm trying to find a way (if there is one) of being able to maintain the rails goodness that you get through something like 'resources' but without the prepended resource name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use:

```
resources :users, :path => '' do
  resources :projects, :path => ''
end
```

And override to_param method of User and Project, for example:

```
class User
  def to_param
    name.parameterize
  end
end
```