# Rails 3: Permalink public profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have `/users/1` as the public user profile (show method) but I'd like to have `/user_name` instead of `/users/1`.

Can I accomplish that if I use devise?

Thanks

**Edit: 
My show controller:**

```
# public profile page
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Get username into URL

You can do it. Devise is just an authentication solution. Your other controllers can behave however you want them to. Here is an overview of the steps that you need to get this URL behavior.

- Ensure that `user_name` is unique for each user
- Override the User's `to_param` method to return `user_name`
- Change the way that you get the user from the database

This would go in your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :validatable
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name

  def to_param
    user_name
  end

end
```

Then, in your controller, do something like this:

```
@user = User.find_by_user_name(params[:id])
```

Helpers like `user_path(@user)` use the `to_param` method to generate the URL.

### Remove controller from URL

As for changing the route from `/user/:id` to just `/:id`. Something like this would work:

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

Here you can use `user_path` and `user_url` because of the `:as => :user`

But you may benefit from reading these:

[How can I implement vanity URL's in a Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137392/how-can-i-implement-vanity-urls-in-a-rails-application)

[How to implement "short" nested vanity urls in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575475/how-to-implement-short-nested-vanity-urls-in-rails)

There are a lot of things to think about when you do it that way.

Comment: That works but I do not want /users/user_name, I want /user_name. How can I change that?

Comment: I updated the answer to include information on how to do that.

Comment: From here, how would you serve it to the view? <%= @user.user.name %> won't work.

Comment: In this example I provided in the answer, the `User` model has a property `user_name`, so you would do it like this: `<%= @user.user_name %>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find by either the username or the id something like this should work:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id]) || User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: That works like /users/username. I want only /username. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, missed that. In that case I've set a route like: map.user_profile '/:id', :controller => :users, :action => 'show', :id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*/ at the *end* of your routes.rb file, the condition on the :id helps it fall through for other routes. Then you'll just need to make sure that your show action does something like render a 404 or redirects home if it doesn't find a user. You can also generate exactly the routes you need in your routes.rb file User.all.each |{ |user| map.connect "/#{user.username}", :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'}, but it's not dynamic.

Comment: @njorden, thanks for that however, if I use that route all my other /routes will not work, it will always search for the user in the /dashboard, etc route.

Comment: It shouldn't if you put it at the very end of the routes file...it should match any other routes first and only match /:id if no others match.

Comment: Man, I was busy editing my answer and... njorden is right. It will match the last route last. However, using the `map.user_profile` syntax will be deprecated soon. You should use `match '/:id' => 'users#show', :constraints => { :id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*/ }, :as => :user_profile` to do the same thing now since you're using Rails 3.

Comment: Didn't notice the rails3 tag, yeah definitely use the new syntax. And overriding to_param is a great way to go if you always want to support the user_name. Often I've found that I needed to support either id or username/slug.

Answer (score 0):

dontangg's answer is mostly right, but there are some very important things his answer is missing.

First, you absolutely should not use straight usernames for the slugs. You need to normalize them in some way and blacklist certain slugs to prevent them from colliding with your resource or action names, something that is especially important when you are using them without the resource prefix in the URL. So, as tee pointed out, the first step is using a slug generation library, and friendly_id is currently the best. Secondly, you need to add your resource names to the friendly_id slug blacklist and handle the exception thrown when an offending slug is generated. You'll generally want to have a `cached_slug` attribute on the sluggable model, and you'll need to expose that in #to_param (eg, `def to_param; cached_slug end`). Then you'll need to update your finders to check on the slug, eg `ModelName.where(:cached_slug => params[:id]).first`

Edit: also, WRT the comment on another answer that recommended using `User.all`, remember that `.all` should never be used on any table that has more than a handful of records. You load the whole table into memory as Ruby objects and can easily bring your server to a standstill.