# Rails: Define routes manually after modifying to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to implement a vanity url for user profiles, based on the example here: [Rails 3: Permalink public profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565031/rails-3-permalink-public-profile). I have replaced the 'id' with username:

```
  def to_param
    username
  end
```

However this has caused issues with my other routes. I have set them so that they match the default sets of routes exactly, when running 'rake routes'.

```
  get '/users/' => 'users#index', :as => :users
  post '/users' => 'users#create'
  get '/users/new' => 'users#new', :as => :new_user
  get '/users/:id/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
  patch '/users/:id' => 'users#update'
  put '/users/:id' => 'users#update'
  delete '/users/:id' => 'users#destroy'

  # for vanity url
  get '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

With this setup, trying to access delete and update routes give me 'no route matches' error. What is the proper way to specify these, and / or should I be doing this a different way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's interresting and more readable to keep the `resources` syntax in the `routes.rb`, except for the `show`, which you can rewrite to customize `user_path` :

```
resources :users, :except => [:show]

# 2 possibilities for the show url    
get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'   # can be removed if you don't want to keep /users/:id url
get '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

But change the controller to find user by `username` instead of `id`, for example

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_username(params[:id])   # instead of Post.find(params[:id])
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Doesn't defining resources :users conflict with specifying ', :as => :user' for the vanity url route? I cannot access the default routes again (edit_user_path, etc) because they are both specified as 'user'. I am trying to replace /users/username with just '/username' as the show route.

Comment: @Drew If you define `get '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user` before `resources :users`, the `user_path` will be the `/:id` (first found).

Comment: @Drew you can also use `resources :users, :except => [:show]` if you want to remove the `users/:id` path.

Comment: Baldrick, I appreciate all of your help. Unfortunately placing resources :users below the vanity url route will cause '/users' to route to /users/show as it thinks 'users' is a username.  The 'update' route gives me No route matches [PATCH] "/username". This has definitely caused me some headaches today for sure :-)

Comment: @Drew you're right, `get '/:id'` have to be at the end. I make one last try, I've updated my answer to rewrite the `show` outside of the `resources :users`.